# inhomogeneous heat equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Find the solution u to the initial value problem 
$$u_t − u_{xx} =sin(x),   u(x,0)=0$$

I know that the particular solution is $u_p = -sin(x)$ So

$u(x,t) = h(x,t) + u_p$

$h(x,t) = u(x,t) - u_p$

$h(x,0) = u(x,0) - u_p(x,0)$

$h(x,0) = 0 + sin(x) = sin(x)$

Now I need to plug $h(x,0)$ into the solution $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-y^2}{4t}}h(x-y,0)dy$

First of all, am I on the right track?

Second of all, how would I simplify this integral? Using $sin(x-y)= sin(x)cos(y) - sin(y)cos(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

$u(x,t) = -\sin(x)$ is a solution to your inhomogeneous PDE, so you want $u(x,t) = h(x,t) - \sin(x)$ where $h(x,t)$ is a solution to the homogeneous PDE $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ with the initial condition
$h(x,0) = u(x,0) + \sin(x) = \sin(x)$.  Now from separation of variables $\sin(a x) e^{-a^2 t}$ is a solution to the homogeneous PDE for any constant $a$.  Taking $a=1$, we get 
$h(x,t) = \sin(x) e^{-t}$ which does satisfy the initial condition.  Thus a solution to your initial value problem is

$$ u(x,t) = -\sin(x) + \sin(x) e^{-t} $$

I say "a solution" rather than "the solution" because solutions are nonunique unless you restrict their growth at $\infty$: see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87464/non-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-the-heat-equation).

Comment: I see that this solution makes sense but I'm not sure what you mean by separation of variables and where you got the idea for $sin(ax)e^{-a^2t}$