# Uniqueness of the solution of the heat equation on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, heat-equation

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth compact Riemannian manifold without boundary. Then there exists a **unique** fundamental solution $p(x,y,t)$ on $M \times M \times (0,\infty)$ that is $C^2$ w.r.t. to $x,y$ and $C^1$ w.r.t. $t$ that satisfies
$$
(\Delta_x-\partial_t) p=0 \quad p(\cdot,y,t) \to \delta_y \quad \text{as } t \to 0.
$$
Furthermore, if $f \in C(M)$ is a continuous function
$$
u(x,t)= \int_M p(x,y,t)f(y) d\mu(y)
$$
is the **unique** solution of the heat equation with initial data $u(\cdot,0)=f(\cdot)$. I quote this from Chavel's book "Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry".

My question now is that if $f \in L^2(M)$, for example if $f=\chi_D(x)$ for some compact subset with a nice boundary,
$$
u(x,t) = \int_D p(x,y,t)d\mu(y)
$$
is the unique solution of the heat equation with initial data $u(\cdot,0)=\chi_D(x)$. Certainly it is a solution, but is it unique? So if $v(x,t) \in C^2(M\times M \times (0,\infty))$ solves the heat equation with initial data $v(x,0)=\chi_D(x)$, does it hold
$$
v(x,t)= \int_D p(x,y,t)d\mu(y)?
$$
I'm not sure if the following works:
Since $u(\cdot,0) \equiv v(\cdot,0)$ almost everywhere
$$
\int_M (u(x,0) - v(x,0))^2 =0
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_M (u(x,t) - v(x,t))^2 d\mu(x) = \int_M 2(u(x,t) - v(x,t))\frac{d}{dt}(u(x,t) - v(x,t)) d\mu(x)\\ =
\int_M 2(u(x,t) - v(x,t))\Delta(u(x,t) - v(x,t)) d\mu(x)\\ = 
-2\int_M |\nabla (u(x,t) - v(x,t))|^2d\mu(x) \leq 0
$$
(last step by using Green's theorem. So that since the term is positive
$$
\int_M (u(x,t) - v(x,t))^2 =0 \quad \text{for all } t\geq 0.
$$
But can I apply Green's theorem?  I'm not sure how smooth $u(x,t)$ is in $t$ direction.

Comment: Is you manifold compact?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, sorry I forgot this condition.

Comment: @ArcticChar Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: It no longer answer your question after your edit.

Comment: To answeer your edited question $u-v$ is smooth whenever $t>0$, so there is no issues in using Green's theorem.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Do you know if the approach also works for noncompact manifolds under certain assumptions?

Comment: Or: since you assumed $v$ is of $C^2$, and the solution $u$ given by heat kernel is smooth, so $v-u$ is $C^2$ and greens theorem is applicable.

Comment: You may read the recent paper "On the uniqueness for the heat equation on complete Riemannian manifolds" on arxiv and the referrence therein.

Answer (score 0):

The difference $v - \int_D p ~\mathrm d \mu$ solves the heat equation (since heat equation is linear) and has $0$ initial condition, and so must be equal to the constant $0$ solution by uniqueness.

Comment: Note that solution to the heat equation is in general not unique if $M$ is noncompact.

Comment: @ArcticChar Good to know. Do you know why, intuitively, that might happen?

Comment: I think the intuition is that uniqueness does not hold: there is a classical example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87464/non-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-the-heat-equation). If you want uniqueness you need to impose extra assumptions.