# Deduce positivity of solution of linear parabolic PDE from non-negative initial data

Tags: maximum-principle, linear-pde

Suppose $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty]$ and $u(x,t)$ is scalar and solves a linear parabolic partial differential equation with $u(\cdot,0)\geq 0$.

Can one apply some maximum or minimum principle to immediately get $u(\cdot,t)>0$ for all $t>0$?

I am new to this business and my feeling is that this should hold but I cannot give a proof.

Comment: No. Indeed it's not true. There are counterexample even when $u(\cdot, 0) = 0$. The example  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87464/non-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-the-heat-equation) is such an example.

Comment: Can one at least deduce that $u(\cdot,t)\geq 0$ for all $t>0$?

Comment: You'll need some sort of "growth estimate". If you have a copy look at Evans section 2.3 theorem 6

Comment: @selector No you can't. Unless you can some extra assumption (e.g. growth conditions on u, integral conditions on u....)

Comment: Okay, let’s assume the necessary conditions are given. How can I deduce the statement?

Answer (score 1):

I give an example of a sufficient set of conditions.
Assume linear elliptic operator
\begin{equation*}
  Lu = -\sum_{ij} a_{ij}u_{x_{i}x_{j}} + \sum_{i} b_{i}u_{x_{i}}+cu
\end{equation*}
with, for positive constants $A$, $B$ and $C$,
\begin{equation*}
  0 \le  a_{ii}\le A \qquad
  -b_{i}x_{i} \le B\left(1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}\right) \qquad
  -c \le C\left(1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}\right).
\end{equation*}
Also smooth $u$ satisfying
\begin{equation*}
  0 \le u_{t}+L u\quad\text{in}\quad \Omega=\mathbb{R}^{n}\times (0,\infty).
\end{equation*}
Also the existence of a positive number $k$ such that
\begin{equation*}
  0 \le \limsup_{r\to\infty}\inf_{\substack{(x,t)\in \bar{\Omega}\\
      \lVert x \rVert=r}}
  u\!\left(x,t\right)e^{-k\left(1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}\right)}
\end{equation*}
(that is the growth condition on $u$).

If we can prove for some fixed $T$ that
$(x,t)\in \Omega_{T}=\mathbb{R}^{n}\times (0,T]$
implies  $0\le u(x,t)$ then we are done,
since we can repeat the argument as necessary
in order to reach any larger value of $t$.
To that end, consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
  g\!\left(x,t\right) &=& e^{k\left(1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}\right)e^{t/T}}\\
  g_{t}\!\left(x,t\right) &=& k/T\left(1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}\right)e^{t/T}g\!\left(x,t\right)\\
  g_{x_{i}}\!\left(x,t\right) &=& 2kx_{i}e^{t/T}g\!\left(x,t\right)\\
  g_{x_{i}x_{j}}\!\left(x,t\right) &=& 2k\left(2kx_{i}x_{j}e^{t/T}+\delta_{ij}\right) e^{t/T}g\!\left(x,t\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
satisfying
\begin{equation*}
g_{t}+Lg
  = 
  \left( \frac{1+\lVert x\rVert^{2}}{T}
    -2\sum_{i}\left(a_{ii}-b_{i}x_{i}\right)
    +\frac{c}{ke^{t/T}}
    -4k e^{t/T}\sum_{ij}a_{ij}x_{i}x_{j}
    \right) k e^{t/T}g.
  \end{equation*}
We should like $T$ such that
$ 0 < g_{t}+Lg$ in $\Omega_{T}$. That is, we want
\begin{equation*}
  4k e^{t/T}\sum_{ij}a_{ij}x_{i}x_{j} +
    2\sum_{i}\left(a_{ii}-b_{i}x_{i}\right)
    -\frac{c}{ke^{t/T}}
    <
    \frac{1+\lVert x\rVert^{2}}{T}.
  \end{equation*}
Because the matrix $\left(a_{ij}\right)$ is symmetric and positive definite,
\begin{equation*}
    \left\lvert
      a_{ij}x_{i}x_{j}
    \right\rvert\le
    \sqrt{a_{ii}a_{jj}}
    \left(1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}\right)
\le A \left(1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}\right)
  \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{4k e^{t/T}}{1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}} \sum_{ij}a_{ij}x_{i}x_{j}
    \le 4 e k n^{2} A.
  \end{equation*}
Also
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{2}{1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}}\sum_{i}\left(a_{ii}-b_{i}x_{i}\right)
    \le 2n\left(A+B\right)
  \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    -\frac{c}{\left(1+\lVert x \rVert^{2}\right)ke^{t/T}}\le \frac{C}{k}.
  \end{equation*}
Thus we can ensure $0 < g_{t}+Lg$ in $\Omega_{T}$ by setting
\begin{equation*}
    T = \frac{1}{1+4ek n^{2}A+2n\left(A+B\right)+C/k}.
  \end{equation*}
With $w=u/g$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  u &=& g w\\
  u_{x_{i}} &=& g w_{x_{i}}+ g_{x_{i}}w\\
  u_{x_{i}x_{j}} &=& g w_{x_{i}x_{j}}+
                     g_{x_{j}}w_{x_{i}}+g_{x_{i}}w_{x_{j}}
                     +g_{x_{i}x_{j}}w\\
  Lu &=& g \left(L-c\right) \! w + 2\sum_{ij}a_{ij}g_{x_{i}}w_{x_{j}}+
         \left(L g \right)w\\
\end{eqnarray*}
so dividing $0\le u_{t}+Lu$ by $g$ gives us
\begin{equation*}
  0 \le w_{t} +
  \left(L-c\right) \! w + \frac{2}{g} \sum_{ij}a_{ij}g_{x_{i}}w_{x_{j}}+
         \frac{1}{g}\left(g_{t}  + L g \right) w.
       \end{equation*}
Since
\begin{equation*}
  0 \le \limsup_{r\to\infty}\inf_{\substack{(x,t)\in\bar{\Omega}_{T} \\
    \lVert x \rVert = r}}w(x,t)
\end{equation*}
there exists sequence $r_{n}$ with $r_{n}\to \infty$ and
\begin{equation*}
  -\frac{1}{n}\le \inf_{\substack{(x,t)\in\bar{\Omega}_{T}\\
    \lVert x \rVert = r_{n} }} w(x,t).
\end{equation*}
We shall prove that for any $n$, and with
$\left(x,t\right) \in \bar{\Omega}_{T}$ satisfying
$\lVert x \rVert \le r_{n}$,
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{1}{n}\le w(x,t).
\end{equation*}
implying $0 \le w$ in $\Omega_{T}$, and $0 \le u$  in turn.

Suppose it false, i.e. that
\begin{equation*}
  \inf_{\substack{(x,t)\in\bar{\Omega}_{T}\\
    \lVert x \rVert \le r_{n} }} w(x,t)<-\frac{1}{n}.
\end{equation*}
Then $w$ must attain its minimum in
$\left\{(x,t)\in \bar{\Omega}_{T} \mid \lVert x \rVert \le r_{n}\right\}$
at some point $\left(x_{0},  t_{0}\right)$
away from the parabolic boundary.
We have
\begin{equation*}
  0 <
  -\frac{1}{g}\left(g_{t}+Lg\right)w \!\left(x_{0},t_{0}\right)
  \le w_{t}\!\left(x_{0},t_{0}\right)-\sum_{ij} a_{ij}w_{x_{i}x_{j}}\!\left(x_{0},t_{0}\right).
\end{equation*}
But we know that $w_{t}\!\left(x_{0},t_{0}\right)$ has to be nonpositive
and that $\sum_{ij} a_{ij}w_{x_{i}x_{j}}\!\left(x_{0},t_{0}\right)$ has to be
nonnegative (skipping over some linear algebra).
Contradiction.