# Heat equation and gradient estimation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Assuming that $u_0 \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and considering the heat equation
$$u_t - \Delta u = 0$$
in $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,+\infty)$ and $u(x,0) = u_0(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is possible to show that some estimative in the following sense:
$$||\nabla u(x,t)|| \leq C(t)||u_0||_{\infty}?$$

Comment: No. Even when $u_0$ is identically zero, $u$ might be non-zero (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87464/non-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-the-heat-equation)).

Comment: Does the condition of $u_0 \in L^{\infty}$ not help solve the uniqueness issue in this case?

Comment: No. You need assumption on the solutions $u(x, t)$. (In the example I linked, $u_0$ is the zero functions, so is bounded).

Comment: In the case of adding a regularity of type $u \in C^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T]) \cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,T ])$ and $u_0 \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, would they be sufficient conditions to guarantee such a result?

Comment: Well, basically, you need conditions on $u_0$ so that $V(x, t) = \int H(x, y, t) u_0(y) dy$ is well-defined, where $H$ is the heat kernel. So the growth conditions on $u_0$ is weak. Then there will be an unique solution $u(x, t)$ with a specific growth conditions (so that $V = u$). It's not the regularity.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327964/estimate-for-the-gradient-nabla-x-u-x-t-in-the-heat-equation).