# Estimate for the gradient $|\nabla_x u (x,t)|$ in the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Suppose $u_0 \in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n).$
Consider
\begin{equation}
\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
       &u_{t} - \Delta u = 0 \ \ &&\mathbb{R}^n \times (0, +\infty),\\
        & u(x,0) = u_0(x) && \mathbb{R}^n\\
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation}
And let $u$ be the solution given in terms of the fundamental solution,
\begin{equation}
u(x,y) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\frac{-|x - y|^2}{4t}}u_0(y) dy
\end{equation}
Show that there is $C > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
|\nabla_x u (x,t)| \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt t}\|u_0\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}, \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \ t > 0
\end{equation}

**Attempt**: For the one-dimensional problem, for example,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u_x(x,t) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 4\pi t}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{d}{dx}e^{\frac{-|x - y|^2}{4t}}u_0(y) dy\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt 4\pi t}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} -\frac{|x - y|}{2t}e^{\frac{-|x - y|^2}{4t}}u_0(y) dy\\
& \leq \frac{1}{4\sqrt \pi t }\frac{1}{\sqrt t}\|u_0\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} |x - y|e^{\frac{-|x - y|^2}{4t}} dy\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
By changing a variable, I'm finding that the integral above gives zero. Help!

Comment: To make this rigorous you must justify why you are allowed to swap the derivative and the integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track; use translation invariance to write
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x-y|e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}\, dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |z|e^{-|z|^2/4t}\, dz.
$$
Now write $w=z/(2\sqrt{t})$ to further write
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x-y|e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}\, dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |2\sqrt{t} w|e^{-|w|^2}\, 2\sqrt{t}dw=4t \int_{-\infty}^\infty |w|e^{-|w|^2}\, dw.
$$
For higher dimensions it's the same, just remember that in that case $dw=(2\sqrt{t})^{-n}\, dz$.

**Added:** In one dimension it's easy to compute the integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |w|e^{-w^2}\, dw = 2\int_0^\infty we^{-w^2}\, dw = \int_0^\infty e^{-s}\, ds =1,
\end{equation}
with $s=w^2$ so that $ds=2w dw$. In higher dimensions you can probably get something in terms of the $\Gamma$ function with the same change of variables.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that you don't actually have to explicitly evaluate the integral once you have translated and rescaled to remove the $x$ and $t$ dependence since then it is just a constant. You just need to note that $z \mapsto e^{-\vert z \vert^2}$ is Schwartz so the integral is finite.