# Only constant solution for Cauchy problem of heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

If

$$
\begin{cases}\partial_{t} u-\Delta u=0, & (t, x) \in[0, T] \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \\ u(0, x)=0, & x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\end{cases}
$$

and for all $(t, x) \in[0, T] \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have $u(t, x) \geq 0$, then $u \equiv 0$.

In my thought, we should impose restriction solution in $B_R$, a bounded ball, and use something like maximal pricipal and let $R\to\infty$. And if a can show that $u(t,x)$'s value on the boundary of $B_R$ decline to zero, then by maximum principle we can get zero solution.

Comment: Energy method would also be a good way to proceed

Comment: @ Ninad Munshi Thank you for advice :) I will try it.

Comment: Is it an exercise? If I understand correctly, it is not that easy to prove.

Comment: @ Arctic Char Yes! And you are right, it is attached with a star, which means hard-level.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions on $u$? If for each $t$, $u(\cdot,t) \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ then you can just take the Fourier transform. But I guess that you're assuming $u \in C^1_tC^2_x(\mathbb R^n \times (0,T))$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87547/629362), it's a theorem of Widder.

Comment: @ Arctic Char Thank you, I will go and check it.